# The purpose of definite articles in the extract

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Can anyone explain me the usage of articles in this extract?

> When students in the UK were asked by a national newspaper what kind of college they would like to go to, they agreed that one of the most important things was the location of **THE** college and the other was the state of **THE** buildings.
>
> *The extract is taken from First Expert textbook.*

It seems to me we neither mention an object (college) for the second time nor we speak about something definite and well-known. We speak about ANY college and buildings of any college. Why do we use definite article with both of them?

Comment: The definite articles refer to "the college they would like to go to", which is what they were asked about. The college exists in their minds, even though it wasn't used as a definite description in the sentence you read. There's more going on than you may  suspect.

Comment: When considering a college, its location and condition are properties of the actual, specific college.

Comment: Yes: 'the college they would like to go to' post-specifies the college involved, licensing 'the'. And here, '[that] they would like to go to' is notional but retrievable (as is the premodifier 'college', for 'the [college] buildings') .

Comment: Any college has a specific location and a specific set of buildings. It's the same reason we say "the roof of a house" and not "a roof of a house". [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+roof+of+a+house%2C+a+roof+of+a+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20roof%20of%20a%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20roof%20of%20a%20house%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Surely there's a duplicate for this. This is analogous to "the most common problem with Ford Tauruses is *the transmission*." Some sort of distributive thingummy for hypotheticals and groups...

Answer (score 0):

**The** is used with a noun that is

(i) **described or indicated:** The college *that they would like to go to*. "The college *I will tell you about* is very old."[pointing] "*Here* is the college!"

(ii) **known to both speaker and audience**: One student to another:"**The** college has asked me to leave"; "Can you see **the** moon?"

Also if it is

(iia) **unique** "**The** Eiffel Tower is taller than **the** Taj Mahal."; "**The** Pope visited France."

(iii) **emphatic**: "No it is not a copy, it is **the** (pron. /ðiː/) axe that cut off the king's head."

(iv) **used for contrast** "Yes, that is a key, but it is not **the** (pron. /ðiː/) key  - I want the key for the door."